# Query based on variable field name

Tags: apex, query, dynamic-soql, database

I would like to know that how can we search based on a custom field via a variable.

For example, if I create a custom field Mobilephone for the standard object Account, then how can I search this custom field Mobilephone?

```
String phone_number = '1';
String param = 'MobilePhone__c';
Account[] a = [select Name, Id, phone, :param from Account where :param =: phone_number];
```

I have tried this, but this doesn't work.

Both the search field and value to be searched have to be used from the variable.

If you know, please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is addressed by using [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

In your case you need to do something like:

```
String phoneNumber = '1';
String param = 'MobilePhone__c';

Account[] accounts = Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, Name, ' + param + ' FROM Account ' +
        'WHERE ' + param + ' = :phoneNumber');
```

Note:

1. Still use a binding variable for values to be substituted into the query to avoid having to mess around with protecting against SOQL injection attacks.
2. You need to make sure that dynamic elements are "clean" (if you get `param` from configuration or user input, for example, you need to validate that it is just a field name, again to avoid SOQL hacks).

One option to verify that "param" is clean is to check this against a regex. A comprehensive regex that allows for namespaces, field paths through related objects and handles geocoordinate compound field members is:

```
^(((([A-Za-z][A-Z-a-z0-9_]{0,14}__)?[A-Za-z][A-Z-a-z0-9_]{0,39}__r|[A-Z][A-Z-a-z0-9]{0,39})\.)*(([A-Za-z][A-Z-a-z0-9_]{0,14}__)?[A-Za-z][A-Z-a-z0-9_]{0,39}__(c|L(at|ong)itude__s)|[A-Z][A-Z-a-z0-9]{0,39}))$
```

You can use Apex's [Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_pattern_methods.htm) class to check that this is matched correctly.

Other options are available, such as splitting the path and using the [Schema API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) to check that each field in the path really exists.

Comment: Please let me know if JSON serialize and deserialize serve the purpose?